# What exactly was the American WW2 smokebomb used in naval warfare?

Tags: military, bomber, wwii

In WW2 the Americans used a kind of smoke/gas-bomb that they mounted under the SBD planes in naval warfare.

What was the purpose of that device and what is it called?

Answer (score 7):

The ocean is featureless, floating smoke bombs were used to mark a spot on a body of water so pilots could get back to the same spot. Smoke plumes can be seen from a long distance, they also let you gauge wind direction and speed.

Smoke bombs were often used when attacking submarines, if a pilot spotted a periscope or caught a sub on the surface before it dove he could drop a smoke marker on the spot before coming around to drop a depth bomb on it. Smoke bombs were also used to mark people in the water, for instance downed pilots or sailors, so they could be rescued.

Comment: Good answer, if you could add the specific devices used (the OP does specify a military and time period), it would be great.

Comment: Do you mean Smoke Floats? Use Google Books search and search for "sbd dauntless smoke float light" will find details.

Answer (score 4):

Page 29 of the [Pilot's Flight Operating Instructions, Navy Model SBD-6 Airplanes](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Douglas_Sbd_Dauntless_Dive_Bomber_Pilot/d0sMQ15sPj8C?hl=en&gbpv=0),
NavAer 01-40SC-I, Sept. 1, 1944, says:

> The five **float lights (night drift signals)** are aft of the flexible gun ammunition box.  These lights are principally used at night to check drift variations, but can also be used during daylight.  The gunner computes the
> amount of drift by means of the smoke, or smoky light, which is released when the float strikes the water.